# jquery Fancybox3 title responsive line break

Tags: jquery, responsive-design, fancybox, line-breaks

Although I´ve read a few post about this, cant find the solution.
I need the fancybox title to fit the screen when displayed in mobiles. In other words, I need the title line to break when it exeeds the width of the vieport, by dividing the title in diferent `<p>` areas.
As a js iliterate, I´ve tried to set a max-with in the css .fancybox-title. I also tried to `<br>` in the html. Dind´t worked out.

the html:

```
<a href="imagenes/picaflor-24.jpg" class="grid-exposicion-item item-picaflor-24 fancybox" rel="gallery" title="DETALLE DE LA INSTALACIÓN PICAFLOR-MADREFLOR | Papel japonés, resina y ramas de guaranguillo | 2016" ></a>
```

the script:

```
// Change title type, overlay closing speed
            $(".fancybox-effects-a").fancybox({
                helpers: {
                    title : {
                        type : 'outside'
                    },
                    overlay : {
                        speedOut : 0
                    }
                }
            });
```

the css:

```
/* Title helper */

.fancybox-title {
    visibility: hidden;
    font: normal 13px/20px "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    position: relative;
    text-shadow: none;
    z-index: 8050;
    
    
}

.fancybox-opened .fancybox-title {
    visibility: visible;
}

.fancybox-title-float-wrap {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 50%;
    margin-bottom: -35px;
    z-index: 8050;
    text-align: center;
}

.fancybox-title-float-wrap .child {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: -100%;
    padding: 2px 20px;
    background: transparent; /* Fallback for web browsers that doesn't support RGBa */
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
       -moz-border-radius: 15px;
            border-radius: 15px;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 2px #222;
    color: #FFF;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 24px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    
}

.fancybox-title-outside-wrap {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 10px;
    color: #fff;
}

.fancybox-title-inside-wrap {
    padding-top: 10px;
}

.fancybox-title-over-wrap {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 10px;
    background: #000;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
}
```

the jquery.fancybox.js:

```
     *  Title helper
     */

    F.helpers.title = {
        defaults : {
            type     : 'float', // 'float', 'inside', 'outside' or 'over',
            position : 'bottom' // 'top' or 'bottom'
        },

        beforeShow: function (opts) {
            var current = F.current,
                text    = current.title,
                type    = opts.type,
                title,
                target;

            if ($.isFunction(text)) {
                text = text.call(current.element, current);
            }

            if (!isString(text) || $.trim(text) === '') {
                return;
            }

            title = $('<div class="fancybox-title fancybox-title-' + type + '-wrap">' + text + '</div>');

            switch (type) {
                case 'inside':
                    target = F.skin;
                break;

                case 'outside':
                    target = F.wrap;
                break;

                case 'over':
                    target = F.inner;
                break;

                default: // 'float'
                    target = F.skin;

                    title.appendTo('body');

                    if (IE) {
                        title.width( title.width() );
                    }

                    title.wrapInner('<span class="child"></span>');

                    //Increase bottom margin so this title will also fit into viewport
                    F.current.margin[2] += Math.abs( getScalar(title.css('margin-bottom')) );
                break;
            }

            title[ (opts.position === 'top' ? 'prependTo'  : 'appendTo') ](target);
        }
    };
```

Can somebody help me with this. Thanks!!